# Up navigation, proper way to handle

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, android-actionbar

I know there are lots of questions about handling Up navigation, but none of them satisfies me.

I have 3 activities: MainActivity, BookActivity, BookChaptersActivity. BookActivity receives some extras to properly initialize. I am using this recommended way to navigate:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

However when using Up navigation inside BookChapterActivity, I am getting back to BookActivity, but it gets recreated without extras, so it is complete mess. 
I know that recommended way to solve this issue is by using:
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
inside manifest. However I don't feel it is proper way to handle this issue. What if I would like to have multiple instances of BookActivity?

So I am asking you: how this situation should be handled properly?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to finish() your BookActivity after starting a BookChapterActivity and starting BookActivity with a new Intent + your extras when returning.

**BookChapterActivity**

```
 @Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: handleBack();break; //Navigation UP Button was pressed.
        default: return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this method to be called:

```
private void handleBack() {
//put your extras in the new intent
    Intent bookActivity = new Intent(this,BookActivity.class);
    bookActivity.putExtra("key","extra");
    startActivity(bookActivity);
    finish();
}
```

**BookActivity** (receiving the information)

```
Intent getBundleExtras = getIntent();
Bundle getBundleExtrasBundle = getBundleExtras.getExtras();
String extra = getBundleExtrasBundle.getString("key");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what about finishing BookChapterActivity without previously finishing BookActivity and starting it with intent? Does this approach has any drawbacks?

Comment: Yes, you'll have this activity in your stack, that means if you want to leave your app on the proper way (Pressing the back or nav-up button), you have to navigate through this activity twice